# MySQL return row if exists, otherwise different row

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Need help with this query...

```
SELECT field_value, file
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE form_name = '" . $form_name . "' AND submit_time = '" . $submit_time . "' AND (field_name = 'csv_parts_file' OR field_name = 'csv_paste_file');
```

Basically, I would like to return just 1 row here, but I need to get the row where `field_name = 'csv_parts_file'` (if exists), but if that does not exist than I need to get the row where `field_name = 'csv_paste_file'` instead.  Am thinking I might need to do a `CASE` here, but not sure how.  Not much experience with CASE statements.

Any help is greatly appreciated here.

Database Table structure as follows:
[image: Database Table structure]

Comment: No need for a case statement at all; just add `ORDER BY field_name LIMIT 1` to yoru existing SQL

Comment: @MarkBaker I am using `$wpdb->get_row` so don't think it will work with that.

Comment: Why don't you think it would work? You believed a complicated CASE would work! The ORDER BY clause will place the `csv_parts_file` first if there's both, or the `csv_parts_file` if there isn't a `csv_parts_file` entry, and LIMIT 1 will only pick that first entry

Comment: Doesn't work using `$wpdb->get_row`, will have to do it using `$wpdb->get_results` which was what I was trying to avoid, since get_results splits it into a deeper array...

Comment: Clear you query and put some original value even it just a sample value it fine. and the result you need. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a little weird way to make it happen, but it should work:

```
SELECT field_value, file, IF(field_name = 'csv_parts_file', 0, 1) as condition
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE form_name = '" . $form_name . "' 
AND submit_time = '" . $submit_time . "' 
AND (field_name = 'csv_parts_file' OR field_name = 'csv_paste_file')
ORDER BY condition
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Not sure an OR is the right answer since it could potentially return >1 row.

Comment: @Jeff How can it return more than 1 row when `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: You're right I missed the LIMIT 1 statement at the end... however, in that case which 1 row would it return? the row that meets the first condition in the OR or the row(s) that meets the second condition?

Comment: That's what you have `ORDER BY condition` for, it will put the one with field_name = 'csv_parts_file' first